# Young adult novel with secret alien society

Tags: story-identification, books

I am trying to remember the name of a young adult (possibly children) sci-fi book.  The story has one main protagonist who is a young teen boy and it turns out he and his family are actually aliens.  The boy did not know this and he is beginning a transformation.  There is also a secret community of aliens. Some elements of the story are:

1.) There is a boy who, we are told, has his appendix burst but this was a cover up for his alien transformation.

2.) There is a glove (possibly metallic) which can be used by aliens (possibly a weapon).

3.) It is possible that the aliens, in their final form, were majestically blue (I can't be certain).

I read the book more than 12 years ago but I have no idea when it was published.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Dark Side of Nowhere by Neal Shusterman.

You can see covers of different editions here: https://www.goodreads.com/work/editions/186438-the-dark-side-of-nowhere

Comment: yes, that's it exactly, thanks!